# Mapping a List inside a List using SerializedName

Tags: java, android, arraylist, serialization, gson

I have an `object class`, called `Device`, inside that there is a `List` of `objects`, which also contains a `List` of `objects`.

Model looks like this:

```
public class Device {
  @SerializedName("tests")
  public List<Test> tests;

  public static class Test {
    @SerializedName("id")
    public String id;

    @SerializedName("testInfo")
    private List<TestInfo> testInfo = new ArrayList<TestInfo>();
  }

  public static class TestInfo {  
    @SerializedName("id")
    private String id;
  }
}
```

Now when it is mapping the request, it maps the first `List`, meaning when printing the result I get this:

```
Test{id='123', testInfo = []}
Test{id='124', testInfo = []}
```

The `testInfo` is always an empty list, even though the data is there. I tried it with and without the `new ArrayList`. Is the problem here that `SerializedName` does not know how to map a list inside a list or am I doing somthing wrong?

**EDIT**
Data that is being mapped:

```
"tests": [
        {
            "id": "123",
            "testInfo": [
                {
                    "id": "321",
                },
                {
                    "id": "322",
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": "124",
            "testInfo": [
                {
                    "id": "421",
                },
                {
                    "id": "422",
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
```

Comment: Where is the data you are mapping ?

Comment: Added the data.

Comment: How are you doing mapping ? Are you using GSON or Moshi or something else? getters and setters are missing for private fields thats why i thought .

Comment: I am using GSON and both the getters and setters are actually present, just didnt add them here. But in theory there should be no problem with having a `Serialized` list inside a list?

Comment: I have to correct myself. I am using Retrofit 2.0 Call for mapping

Comment: Fix your JSON in question. Needs wrapping `{ }`  and has extra `,` after _testInfo.id_.